# KDE and gnome canvas

Tags: gnome, kubuntu, kde

Is gnome canvas supported by KDE ? Etherape Crashes when opened within KDE and complains that gnome canvas isnt supported. If this is true is there a way of importing "gnome canvas".
Or are there any other known workarounds ?

Comment: Please provide more information on the crash screnario. Generally, it is possible to use Gnome Canvas in KDE Plasma environments, yes.

Answer (score 0):

From https://etherape.sourceforge.io/ - Overview of changes in EtherApe 0.9.18 (Sunday, June 3, 2018): EtherApe now is a pure GTK 3 application, with canvas supplied by GooCanvas.

Install GooCanvas, then install "Shutter" and reboot - works for me.